# How do I correctly use PCA followed by Logistic Regression?

Tags: python, pca, logistic-regression

In the program, I am scanning a number of brain samples taken in a time series of 40 x 64 x 64 images every 2.5 seconds. The number of 'voxels' (3D pixels) in each image is thus ~ 168,000 ish (40 * 64 * 64), each of which is a 'feature' for an image sample.

I thought of using Principle Component Analysis (PCA) because of the rediculously high `n` to perform dimensionality reduction. I am aware PCA does not actually reduce the number of features. Correct me if I'm wrong, but PCA will produce a new set of features  from the original ones. The new features however must follow certain conditions.

I definined a method to get the number of components :

```
def get_optimal_number_of_components():
    cov = np.dot(X,X.transpose())/float(X.shape[0])
    U,s,v = svd(cov)

    S_nn = sum(s)

    for num_components in range(0,s.shape[0]):
        temp_s = s[0:num_components]
        S_ii = sum(temp_s)
        if (1 - S_ii/float(S_nn)) <= 0.01:
            return num_components

    return s.shape[0]
```

This function will return the number of components such that 99% of the variance from the original data is retained. Now, we can create these components :

```
#Scaling the values
X = scale(X)

n_comp = get_optimal_number_of_components()
print 'optimal number of components = ', n_comp

pca = PCA(n_components = n_comp)
X_new = pca.fit_transform(X)
```

I get the optimal number of components = 1001 on running the program on this dataset. This number agrees with the plot I obtained on executing :

```
#Cumulative Variance explains
var1 = np.cumsum(np.round(pca.explained_variance_ratio_, decimals=4)*100)

plt.plot(var1)
plt.title('Principle Component Analysis for Feature Selection')
plt.ylabel('Percentage of variance')
plt.xlabel('Number of voxels considered')

plt.show()
```

After this PCA stage is complete, I used the newly created 'X_new' in place of X for the next stage : Logistic Regression

```
#After PCA
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_new, y, test_size=0.10, random_state=42)

classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

When I test for the accuracy, I get around **77.57%**

But this is less than when I just analysed the middle voxel samples (like 9K samples in the middle of brain image). I was wondering if I pipelined PCA and logistic regression correctly.

I even tried this in another method using `sklearn.pipeline` :

```
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca', pca), ('logistic', classifier)])

pipe.set_params(pca__n_components = n_comp).fit(X_train,y_train)

print 'score = ', pipe.score(X_test,y_test)
```

But I got the exact same accuracy of 77.57%. Am I implementing PCA + Logistic Regression Correctly? There must be something wrong, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: try using TPOT to get the best model and configuration.  Have you thought about using stepwise refinement on feature discovery?

Comment: PCA is used to determine what features can be removed without much lose in model accuracy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't immediately find any error, you should try and test how the error behaves if you increase the `number of components`. Maybe there is some low variance information missing to give the logistic regression the edge it needs?

The `99%` in PCA are more a guideline than fact.

Other things you could try:
Instead of PCA just remove every feature with *zero (or very low) variance*. DTI data often has features that never change, and are therefore completely unnecessary for classification.

Try finding features that correlate strongly with your result and try only using these to classify.

Always be careful **not to overfit!**

> Correct me if I'm wrong, but PCA will produce a new set of features
>   from the original ones.

I will try to describe it as untechnical as possible

Yes. PCA is basically a fancy [axis transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes). Yes you get a new set of features, but they are linear combinations of the previous features in a ordered way such that the first feature describes as much as possible of the data.

The idea is that, if you have a hyperplane, PCA will actually *project the hyperplane* to the first axes and leave the last ones nearly empty.

PCA is **linear** dimensionality reduction, so if the true data distribution is not linear, it gives worse results.

Also a friend of mine worked with Brain data similar to yours (lots of features, very little examples) and PCA almost never helped. It might be that the significant pieces of information are not found because too much "noise" is around.

EDIT: Typo

Comment: I think you hit the nail on its head. I included an extra step before performing PCA. It was to select the k best features. I used `sklearn.feature_selection` to do so. It turns out after selecting 20,000 voxels as features, the accuracy goes down. With k = 20,000 I now get an accuracy as high as 92%! The best part is, the program is pretty darn fast because of PCA.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I found using a MLPClassifer was more accurate for the cc default set.   I added a PCA to my pipeline and then access it to see what features can be removed.

PCA purpose
1. same data with less features
2. assumes low variance are noise
3. specify how many features to keep

```
    pipeline= Pipeline([
    ('scaler',StandardScaler()),
    ('pca', PCA()),
    #('clf2',LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, tol=0.1)),
    ('clf',MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(36,150,36),  max_iter=100, solver='adam', 
             activation='relu', 
             alpha=0.1, 
             learning_rate_init=0.001,
             verbose=False,
             momentum=0.9,
             random_state=42))
     ])
     pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
     y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
     cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)

     class_names=[1,2]
     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     tick_marks = np.arange(len(class_names))
     plt.xticks(tick_marks, class_names)
     plt.yticks(tick_marks, class_names)
     sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(cm), annot=True, cmap="coolwarm" ,fmt='g')
     ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
     plt.tight_layout()
     plt.title('Confusion matrix', y=1.1)
     plt.ylabel('Actual label')
     plt.xlabel('Predicted label')

     print("Test Accuracy is %s",pipeline['clf'].score(X_test,y_test)*100)

     pred_train=pipeline.predict(X_train)
     print("Train Accuracy is %s",accuracy_score(y_train, pred_train))
     
     pca=pipeline['pca']
     pca_features=pca.components_
     

     fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
     # Assign 1st column of pca_features: ys
     xs = pca_features[:,0]
     ys = pca_features[:,1]
     sns.scatterplot(x=xs, y=ys)

     mean = pca.mean_
     first_pc = pca.components_[0,:]
     # Plot first_pc as an arrow, starting at mean
     plt.arrow(mean[0],mean[1], first_pc[0], first_pc[1],       color='red', width=0.01)

     plt.axis('equal')
     plt.show()

     fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))
     features = range(pca.n_components_)
     ax.bar(features, pca.explained_variance_)
     plt.xticks(features)
     plt.ylabel('variance')
     plt.xlabel('pca features')
     plt.show()
```